# Open folder as another user

Tags: users

There is a method by which I can open any folder (or execute any operation) as root (using sudo). Is there any method I can use to open a folder or execute any operation as some other user on the system. I need this because I have two users on the system. Sometimes; I need to use stuff from other user's home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo is a commad that might be best read as "SetUser Do" command:

The command can also be executed as

`sudo -u username docommand.foo`

see `man sudo`

Comment: sudo -u username cd  /home/username doesn't work though

Comment: You'd have to be smarter than I to figure out why.  I suspect that it has to do with the fact that `cd` is one of the built-in commands.

Comment: What is meant by "built-in" commands, and why is it that we can't run `cd` after running `sudo` ? I solved the problem by signing into the other account and doing `chmod 777 /home/username/` so that other users can `cd` into the first user's /home directory, but this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Several commands are part of the shell that you are running, typically Bash.  Others as Sh, and Csh, Zsh...  A more suitable solution for your situation may be to assign yourself to a group, and give that group permissions to the directory, rather than assign local permissions.  Another alternative if you are looking for access on an occasional basis, might be to execute `sudo -i -u <username>` which would leave you as that user until you execute `exit`

Comment: It's unfortunate that one would need to "become" the user, and then remember to press "exit" afterwards. Sure I can make a group and give permissions to the group, but if I'm an administrator, why can't I just `cd` into my own directory on a different account? I have the `sudo` password for both the current account and the other account.

Comment: There may be another way around, but I'm not really proficient with the ins and outs of security.

Comment: I'm not really asking about the ins and outs of security.

Comment: @user1271772 Working with `sudo` implies user security, and invoking super user priviledges

Comment: I now appreciate that you are not proficient with the ins and outs of using `sudo` (which means you're in the same boat as me). To know the ins and outs of security would be an even more general thing which I think is not needed in this case.